# maximum sum of sub ractangle in matrix (2D)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I'm trying to solve the problem with finding the maximum sum of a sub rectangle in a matrix. So far I have managed to implement around 90% of the algorithm. (For any of you who do not know what I'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCQN096CwWM)

My problem is that I do not know how to remove the top or bottom values of my temp array, if they are negative. Not to mention how to know which index the deleted negative values were comming from.

I have solved the problem in 1 dimension (1D) like this:

```
int maxSoFar = 0;
int maxEndingHere = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " + " + input[i]);
        if (maxEndingHere + input[i] > 0) {
            maxEndingHere += input[i];
        } else {
            maxEndingHere = 0;
        }
        if (maxSoFar < maxEndingHere) {
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxSoFar);
```

In two dimensions (2D) I have gotten this far:

```
    int[][] input = new int[4][5];
    input[0][0] = 2;
    input[0][1] = 1;
    input[0][2] = -3;
    input[0][3] = -4;
    input[0][4] = 5;
    input[1][0] = 0;
    input[1][1] = 6;
    input[1][2] = 3;
    input[1][3] = 4;
    input[1][4] = 1;
    input[2][0] = 2;
    input[2][1] = -2;
    input[2][2] = -1;
    input[2][3] = 4;
    input[2][4] = -5;
    input[3][0] = -3;
    input[3][1] = 3;
    input[3][2] = 1;
    input[3][3] = 0;
    input[3][4] = 3;
    int currentSum = 0;
    int maxSum = 0;
    int L;
    int R;
    int maxR = 0;
    int maxL = 0;
    int maxUp = 0;
    int maxDown = 0;
    int k;
    int j;
    int[][] temp = new int[4][1];

    for (L = 0; L < input.length; L++) {
        temp[0][0] = 0;
        temp[1][0] = 0;
        temp[2][0] = 0;
        temp[3][0] = 0;
        for (R = L; R < input[0].length; R++) {
            currentSum = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < temp.length; k++) {
                temp[k][0] += input[k][R];
                if (currentSum + input[k][R]<0){
                    currentSum += input[k][R];
                }
                else {currentSum = 0;}
                if (k == 3 && currentSum >= maxSum) {
                    maxSum = currentSum;
                    maxR = R;
                    maxL = L;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max sum = " + maxSum);
    System.out.println("Max R = " + maxR);
    System.out.println("Max L = " + maxL);
```

This is my first post in here, so please let me know if I'm missing something or the like..

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, here is the working code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Algoritme4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    algo2D(new int[][]{
            {2, 1, -3, -4, 5},
            {0, 6, 3, 4, 1},
            {2, -2, -1, 4, -5},
            {-3, 3, 1, 0, 3}
    });
}

private static int[] algo4(int[] a) {
    int maxEndingHere = 0;
    int i;
    int[] result = {0, 0, 0};
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (maxEndingHere + a[i] > 0) {
            maxEndingHere += a[i];
        } else {
            maxEndingHere = 0;
            result[1] = i + 1;
        }
        if (result[0] < maxEndingHere) {
            result[0] = maxEndingHere;
            result[2] = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max sum of sub matrix = " + result[0] + " (" + result[1] + "," + result[2] + ")");
    return result;
}
private static void algo2D(int[][] a){
    int[] result = {0,0,0};
    int maxSoFar = 0;
    int maxR = 0;
    int maxL = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int slut = 0;
    int L;
    int R;
    int k;

    for (L = 0; L<a.length; L++) {
        int[] temp = {0,0,0,0};
        for (R = L; R < a[0].length; R++){
            System.out.println("R = " + R);
            System.out.println("L = " + L);
            for (k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
                temp[k] += a[k][R];
                if (k==3) {
                    System.out.println("temp = " + Arrays.toString(temp));
                    result = algo4(temp);
                }
                if (result[0]> maxSoFar){
                    maxSoFar = result[0];
                    maxL = L;
                    maxR = R;
                    start = result[1];
                    slut = result[2];
                }

            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max: " + maxSoFar + " (" + maxL + "," + start + ") (" + maxR + "," + slut + ")");
}
```

}